# Vectorize a for loop based on condition using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have 2 numpy arrays `l1` and `l2` as follows:

```
start, jump = 1, 2
L = 8

l1 = np.arange(start, L)
l2 = np.arange(start + jump, L+jump)
```

This results in:

```
l1 = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
l2 = [3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

Now, I want 2 resultant arrays `r1` and `r2` such that while appending elements of `l1` and `l2` one by one in `r1` and `r2` respectively, it should check if `r2` does not contain $i^{th}$ element of `l1`.

Implementing this using for loop is easy. But I am stuck on how to implement it using only numpy (without using loops) as I am new to it.

This is what I tried and want I am expecting:

```
r1 = []
r2 = []

for i in range(len(l1)):
    if (l1[i] not in r2):
        r1.append(l1[i])
        r2.append(l2[i])
```

This gives:

```
r1 = [1, 2, 5, 6]
r2 = [3, 4, 7, 8]
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are the arrays always range-like arrays?

Comment: This is also probably the most direct option, you could speed it up using a set, but I don't know if numpy vectorize operations are a good fit for it

Comment: Your problem is tough to vectorize because the required behavior for element i is dependent on the results of the computations done for the previous iterations. The for loop is probably the best you can do.

Comment: @DaniMesejo yes the arrays are always range like arrays

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs What if we know that the arrays are always range like, even then is it difficult to vectorize?

Comment: In that case, I suspect that r1 and r2 will always follow some sort of pattern dependent on start, jump and L. It might be most efficient to construct them directly using those values

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs Sounds interesting. Let me try to find a possible pattern (if any). Thanks

Comment: For simple operations like addition, functions like `add.accumulate` and `cumsum` can handle sequential loops.  For more custom steps, the best you can do is "step back" and look at the big picture, and see if there's a non-sequential way of solving the problem.  "vectorize" in `numpy` means to treat the arrays in as a whole; they do loops in compiled code, but you have not control over the order or details.

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs I guess I found a pattern. It is something like selecting first `jump` indices and then skipping next `jump` indices and then again selecting next `jump` indices and so on. Can you now tell me how can I do it in numpy (if possible)

Comment: Not sure if that's the exact pattern, but you can do what you describe by making a boolean mask: (eg [True, True, False, False, True, True, False, False, ...] the same length as l1, l2, and then using that as index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Chrysoplylaxs in comments, I made a boolean mask and it worked like a charm!

```
mask = np.tile([True]*jump + [False]*jump, len(l1)//jump).astype(bool)
r1 = l1[mask[:len(l1)]]
r2 = l2[mask[:len(l2)]]
```